# Parse XML, date formats (PT0H0M0S,PT2920H0M0S)

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, ms-project

I'm trying to parse an xml-file exported from MS Project 2013 using python and it contains the following data:

```
<TimephasedData>
    <Type>1</Type>
    <UID>4628</UID>
    <Start>2014-09-22T08:00:00</Start>
    <Finish>2015-09-22T08:00:00</Finish>
    <Unit>8</Unit>
    <Value>PT2920H0M0S</Value>
</TimephasedData>
<TimephasedData>
    <Type>1</Type>
    <UID>4628</UID>
    <Start>2015-09-22T08:00:00</Start>
    <Finish>2015-09-23T08:00:00</Finish>
    <Unit>2</Unit>
    <Value>PT8H0M0S</Value>
</TimephasedData>
```

What I don't understand is what the PT8H0M0S and PT2920H0M0S represents ([TimephasedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968479(v=office.12).aspx)). Currently I parse the dates by replacing the character "T" and then use [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a ISO 8601 time duration value. Compare the [iCal duration data type](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/duration-t.html) spec, which uses this notation:

> ## Formal Definition
>
> The value type is defined by the following notation:
>
> ```
> dur-value  = (["+"] / "-") "P" (dur-date / dur-time / dur-week)
> dur-date   = dur-day [dur-time]   
> dur-time   = "T" (dur-hour / dur-minute / dur-second)
> dur-week   = 1*DIGIT "W"
> dur-hour   = 1*DIGIT "H" [dur-minute]
> dur-minute = 1*DIGIT "M" [dur-second]  
> dur-second = 1*DIGIT "S"
> dur-day    = 1*DIGIT "D"
> ```

So `PT8H0M0S` is time-duration (`T`), 8 hours (`8H`), 0 minutes (`0M`), 0 seconds (`0S`). (The `P` stands for "Period", of course).

There is at least one Python package that can handle transforming these kinds of values, for example https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isodate.